# drop down menu Foundation JavaScript tigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I create simple drop down menu using Foundation 6

```
    <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now i want to on different event ( like other button to hide or show menu.) But in doc there is no method to do this. When I use jquery trigger on click also not working is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Do you want the dropdown to also show when a different button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler to an element (for example a button) and give it a function like hiding the dropdown menu:

```js
$("button").click(function(){$(".dropdown").hide()})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
<ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
<button>
I'm a button
</button>
```

To allow it to come back again, try `$("button").click(function(){$(".dropdown").toggle()})`

Comment: It will work but i want to use it as foundation event. http://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/zrYGjx example dropdown